# Java DataInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, endianness

Client side:

```
        out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        String process;
        System.out.println("Connecting to server on "+ host + " port " + port +" at " + timestamp);
        process = "Connection: "+host + ","+port+","+timestamp; 
        System.out.println("client len " + process.length());
        out.write(process.length());
```

Prints:
Client len 55

Server side:

```
       in = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
       while (true) {
            int len = in.readInt();
            System.out.println("Length of pkt: "+len);
```

Prints: Length of pkt: 927166318

What's going on here? I tried writing 0 and it printed 3621743 on the server side. I checked some other sites and a few people had problems with other streams.  I read about the issues arising with big vs little endianness, but I am not sure what the problem is here since I am using the data*streams that should work fine with each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `readInt()` on one side, you should call [`writeInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeInt%28int%29) on the other. Change this

```
out.write(process.length());
```

to

```
out.writeInt(process.length());
```

From the Javadoc for [`write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write%28int%29),

> Writes the specified byte (the low eight bits of the argument b) to the underlying output stream.

Comment: Perfect.  I knew it was something basic.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `out.writeInt(process.length());` instead of `out.write(...);` since you read an Integer from the stream afterwards.